# Why are there a lot of non-public low-level Java methods ending in 0?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I like to poke around the Java source with IntelliJ. However, I have noticed something strange. Some non-public methods, particularly those in low-level classes, end in `0`. This is most often the case with native methods, however I have observed some non-native methods with this name too. For example, `java.lang.reflect.Executable#getAnnotatedReturnType0(Type)`, and `java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject#setAccessible0(boolean)`. The former simply sets two boolean flags! What is the reasoning behind this strange convention?

Comment: They're probably helper functions/methods of the functions/methods that bear their same name without the trailing `0`. Look at the functions/methods that bear their same names without the trailing `0` and see if they make calls to the functions/methods with a trailing `0`.

Comment: For instance [`BufferedReader#read1(char cbuf[], int off, int len)`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedReader.java#l202) and [`BufferedReader#read(char cbuf[], int off, int len)`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedReader.java#l276).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a somewhat common convention for helper methods.

Java does not allow methods-in-methods (though there is some traffic about adding them). Sometimes you have a repetitive task that nevertheless doesn't fit properly in a looping structure (such as a while or for loop) and doesn't easily fit in a lambda (because its parameter + checked exception requirements don't line up to a convenient type, or the code predates JDK8).

The JDK itself, and some other projects, use the convention of: helper methods get the same name it is a helper for, with a single digit suffix, generally 0 (if there are more helpers, they'd be 1, 2, etc).

This is particularly common with overloading. Let's say you have the following method signature:

```
/**
 * Detaches a disk from a virtual computer.
 * The disk must have been unmounted already on the virtual PC, unless
 * the {@code force} parmater is true, but note that (long story
 * about the perils of force disconnecting here).
 *
 * @param computerId computer to detach the disk from.
 * @param diskId ID of disk to detach
 * @param force Force the issue even if the disk is in use.
 * @throws DiskInUseException If the disk is in use. Never thrown if
 * {@code force} is {@code true}.
 */
public void detachDisk(
   String computerId, String diskId, boolean force) throws DiskInUseException { ... }
```

That's a *bad* API. It's got all sorts of ugly warts on it:

- The docs specify a lot of caveats that literally do not apply whatsoever if I set `force` to `false`.
- It throws a checked exception that may never occur, which is always bad (don't force calling code to catch impossible exceptions, obviously!) - if `force` is `true`, the `DiskInUseException` cannot occur.
- If I call it: `detachDisk(computer, disk, true)` and I see that in code, I can guess that `computer` is a variable referring to a virtualPC, same for `disk` but whatever might `true` be about? I might guess that it's about forcing things, but maybe in my head that third parameter is `safely` (the reverse of `force`).

We can solve a few issues by using an enum instead of a boolean, but that leaves the rest. This is vastly superior API design:

```
/**
 * Same text, but leave out all the stuff about the dangers of forcing.
 * @see #forceDetachDisk(String, String)
 */
public void detachDisk(String computerId, String diskId)
   throws DiskInUseException {..}

/**
 * Same, but now highlight the dangers of forcing.
 * @see #detachDisk(String, String)
 */
void forceDetachDisk(String computerId, String diskId) { .. }
```

Muuuch better, but most likely these 2 methods share most of the implementation. That naturally leads to making this thing:

```
private void detachDisk0(String computerId, String diskId,
   boolean force) throws DiskInUseException { .. }
```

which is private so the confusion and warts it has don't matter, and the public detachDisk methods will simply call the private one. However, some auto-complete dialogs, and certainly most java compilers including `javac` itself, do recognize calls to private methods and will 'helpfully' alert you about the fact that it does exist, and would you perhaps like to change its accessor keyword (if it's a source file and not a class dep)? - That's not so nice. Toss that 0 in there to lessen the effect, and to make more clear that the private method is meant **solely** to be invoked by the 0-less methods and no other method; you wrote it with only its usage from the `detachDisk` method, and not any other method, not even in the same source file.

That's an API design more projects should be using.

Comment: Thank you! This is a really great in-depth explanation!

Answer (score 0):

This "convention" has been used not only for Java. I remember seeing the same in C#.  Usually you will see a public method with the same name (without the zero at the end) calling the private method ending in zero.

But anyway, this naming convention for a private method is not a good example or something you should copy.